# For any positive-definite matrix $A$, there exists a $x\in\Bbb R^n$, such that each component of $Ax$ is greater than $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

For any positive-definite matrix $A$, show that there exists a $x\in\Bbb R^n$, such that each component of $Ax$ is greater than $0$.

How to prove it? If $A$ is just diagonal, say $diag(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$, then it is OK by $x=(1,\cdots,1)'$. For the general, any ideas?

Comment: Your idea is just fine: any symmetric matrix is (orthogonally, even) diagonalizable, so bring your matrix to diagonal form. Of course, all the diagonal elemnets in that form are positive (thyese are the matrix's eigenvalues), so under some basis of the linear space you have exactly the case you mention at the end...and that's all !

Comment: @DonAntonio Changing basis to one where the linear transformation $A$ becomes diagonal is precarious here, as we want a vector with particular coordinates in the initial basis. At the very least, it is nowhere near as trivial as the answer by Lazy.

Comment: @Arthur I can't see where it is written that we want a vector with particular coordinates. It is writen in the question that it must be proved that "there exists" such a vector...and no basis at all of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ has been determined! Thus, I'd say we're free to choose any basis we want...

Comment: @DonAntonio In that case, this question is rather trivial for any non-zero matrix. Just take any vector $x$ not in the kernel and choose a basis such that $Ax=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$. No, the only sensible way to read this question the way I see it is that the fact that we are talking about a matrix and not a linear transformation means a basis has already been picked for us.

Comment: @Arthur Nop. That's wrong since not every matrix is diagonalizable...! And even if you take a diagonalizable matrix it may be that not all its eigenvalues are positive, as  it is  in this case. Symmetric matrices, as gotten by the Spectral Theorem, are so important, among other reasons, because they are (orthogonally) diagonalizable. And it is completely fine to use this fact here as it isn't otherwise stated. In fact, it is using this fact that this exercise is almost trivial or, at least, very easy to solve, as the OP himself remarked in his question

Comment: @DonAntonio Where in  the first half of my previous comment was diagonalizability or positive eigenvalues even remotely relevant?

Comment: @DonAntonio Careful: The question does *not* assume symmetry of $A$!

Comment: @Lazy Positive and negative (semi)definiteness is almost never used without symmetry, and it is much more common to let definiteness implicitly imply symmetry than it is to use definiteness without symmetry. Technically you are right, but DonAntonio made a _very_ reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Arthur No, this is not at all a reasonable assumption. This would then be a case of inductive proof, which is logically not correct, arguing that since a property holds in a special case it has to hold in all cases. In fact I’ve never seen a case where the assumption was made that definiteness implies symmetry. Note that a simple rotation matrix is strictly positive definite but has not a single eigenvalue as long as the angle is sufficiently small.

Comment: @Lazy Arthur is right. Usually, symmetry is included in the definition. While some authors extend this definition to non-symmetric matrices, there is no universally accepted definition of what it means for a non-symmetric matrix to be positive/negative (semi-)definite (like how we have to define what $0^0$ means). If an author wishes to extend the definition, they have to state explicitly, otherwise people will assume that the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: @Lazy I'm not in any way saying that the statement "$xAx>0$ for all non-zero $x$" implies that $A$ is symmetric. I am saying that when someone chooses to use the term "positive definite" to describe $A$, they _very often_ also mean symmetric, but leave it out for brevity or something. (And similar with the other definite-s.)

Comment: @Arthur Yes, but in this question it does *not*, which I am pointing out.

Comment: @Lazy For matrices, definitiveness, either positive or negative, o semi-positive and etc., is defined ONLY for symmetric matrices...Other thing is a *positive matrix*, which is something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is quite trivial. Any (strictly) positive definite matrix has to be injective and thus also bijective and invertible.

Else there would be an $x\neq0$ so that $Ax = 0$, so $x^\mathrm T A x = 0$, which would contradict positive definiteness. But if $A$ is invertible then in fact for each $y\in\mathbb R^n$ there exists an $x$ so that $Ax = y$. So you are free to choose any $y>0$ you like.

Comment: Whow wouldn't there be some vector $\;x\;$ such that $\;Ax\;$ has some component zero or negative, yet when we do $\;x^tAx\;$ we get a positive number? Your "else" doesn't seem to follow from negating what's needed to be proved. In fact, it should be "else there is a non-positive component in $\;Ax\;$ and..." ...etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio The entire "else" section is a proof of the lemma that $A$ is invertible. Once you've proven $A$ is invertible, they point out you can pick any $y$ in the first hyper-quadrant, and use $x=A^{-1}y$ entirely without issue.

Comment: Ah, ok: it was about invertibility...which is trivial since all the matrix's eigenvalues are non-zero.

Comment: @DonAntonio I thing the argument I’ve given for invertibility is slightly more trivial and obvious than arguing with eigenvalues. Here we argue that $Ax = 0$ breaks the pos. def. constraint, while with eigenvalues we argue that $Ax = \lambda x$ with $\lambda \leq 0$ breaks this constraint.

Comment: @Lazy I don't think it is. diagonalizable matrices is something they learn, usually, in a first introductory course in Linear Algebra, whereas inner product, positive/definite matrices and etc. is a latter subject...again, usually.

Comment: @DonAntonio Even if so you’d still need to argue why all eigenvalues $>0$ implies injectivity, which is similarly trivial to the proof given in my answer.

Comment: @Lazy Your explanation is fine...when using the bilinear functional notation (or in fact a quadratic form) $\;q(x):=x^tAx\;$, which is an inner product iff $\;A\;$ is positive definite. Yet this fact is usually covered earlier in L. Algebra, when we see eigenvalues and the fact that $\;A\;$ is singular (i.e., non-injective = not an automorphism) iff zero is one of its eigenvalues. That's why when we reach bilinear (quadratic) forms in the syllabus, we already know that if a matrix is positive/negative definite, then it automatically is an automorphism of the linear space we're working with.